# How do I figure out what field a question or problem belongs to?

Tags: soft-question

Are there guidelines somewhere? I have no significant background in math, but on my own I have come across some things that have really started to capture my imagination. I don't where to go from where I am now.

*note: I added the soft-question tag as I couldn't find a placeholder. I hope it suffices.

Comment: There are [various lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_mathematics_topics#Areas_of_advanced_mathematics), I suppose, though at the end of the day, it's a bit of a catch-22: by doing lots of maths you will become more familiar with the broad outlines of different areas of maths, which makes it much easier to formulate questions and research further.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mathematics

Comment: Thanks. That is a decent page.

Answer (score 1):

Asking on `math.stackexchange` about a problem you have is a decent way to find out what branch of math your question lies in :)

To recieve a broad introduction to branches of pure math, I'd recommend:

- [An infinitely large napkin by Evan Chen](https://web.evanchen.cc/napkin.html) --- this books sketches out a good chunk of pure math, with more of an algebraic flavour. It allows one to survey the "flavour" of a lot of math.
- [The princeton companion to mathematics](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691118802/the-princeton-companion-to-mathematics) is a rigorous introduction to many different branches of pure math
- [The art of computer programming](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html) --- a collection on all things algorithmic or computation related.
- [Course of theoretical Physics / Landau Lifschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_of_Theoretical_Physics) --- While these are technically physics books, they cover the mathematical ground quite well, and are good to learn most of the math that's used in "old-school" physics

Comment: Thanks. I'll give the second book a go. As for asking more detailed questions here, I'm just not up to describing some of these things without having read some related literature. If I were to, I'd just leave a lot of people guessing as to what I actually mean.